# Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit, how can i solve this

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

This is channel.service.spec.ts. i am beginner in nodejs and testing service class. how can i solve this error. thanks

```
describe('ChannelService', () => {
  let service: ChannelService;
  let policy: Policy[]
  const mockChannelService = {
    getChannelPolicies: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([policy]),
  };

 
  beforeEach(async () => {
    GeonoonNacos(rootPath, settings, false, true);
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [ChannelService],
    })
      .overrideProvider(ChannelService)
      .useValue(mockChannelService)
      .compile();

    service = module.get<ChannelService>(ChannelService);
  });

  it('should be defined',  () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
  // Unit test for channel-Service to get related policies of channel from db
  it('should get related policies of channel from db', async () => {
    expect(await service.getChannelPolicies(5)).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Nitesh yahdev, thanks but i get the solutions.

Comment: So what were they?  Someone else might have the same question.

Comment: Can you please post the solution ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. bassically i was using my organization's developed nacos, you can see in my code geonoonnacos. the problem was rootpath was wrong and after correcting rootpath my code works well